# Git adding, committing, and pushing from a website

Tags: javascript, python, html, git, github

I'm making a website as a collaboration tool. Several people could be using it, and I need the ability to, from the website, be able to add, commit, and push to git for all users. I had several ideas, but don't know how they'll pan out. Here are some of them:

1. Create an external Python program waiting for an event from the website. Then the Python program could access the terminal on the local machine and run the necessary commands to add, commit, and push to git.
    The issue with that is that the Python program would have to be running constantly on the local machine of every user of the website. I don't plan to have too many, but I think this would be **VERY** inconvenient.
2. Use some complicated JavaScript program to scrape GitHub and automate add, commit, and push through there. Don't think this is a good idea, but I'm open to it.

Will any of these work for what I need? If so, how would I implement them? Is there a formal way of adding, committing, and pushing to Git over the internet that I'm oblivious to? I've done a ton of research and come up empty-handed.

**EDIT**
Somebody in the comments suggested using the Github API. I didn't find anything useful, but if I'm not seeing something please point it out. I'm specifically looking for something to replace the usual `git add .`, `git commit -m "message"` and `git push` commands, but for my website to automate this.

Comment: Scrape github? Could you not use a js git library?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm new when it comes to JavaScript, but not when it comes to Python. I have no idea what you are talking about. But if you think it'll work, leave and answer and explain how to implement it.

Comment: Then what about a python git library? https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/ Skip the github scraping entirely.

Comment: That seems nice, but I don't see how that is better than sending a command to the terminal which is easily done in 2 lines. But that brings me back to my question regarding my option 1, is there a feasible and not really inconvenient way to do that? Adding Python to a website that already has JavaScript seems overkill for the very small website I'm making. Literally, its just a few iframes and 1 JS function.

Comment: What about looking into the github api? https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: As I'm reading over that, I don't find any information that would help me. It doesn't explain how to replace the git add git commit and git push commands.

Comment: Ok then. Take option 1, but run the python program for every user, but run it on your server. Do all of the commands there.